# ST_Overlaps and ST_intersects

Tags: postgresql, gis, postgis

I have the following query:-

```
SELECT 
  ST_Overlaps(a,b) AS a_overlap_b 
FROM 
  (SELECT ST_GeomFromText 
    ('LINESTRING(-118.291686 34.018886,-118.292677 34.022562,-118.291231 34.025650,-118.2906224 34.0244091,-118.286493 34.020362)') 
    AS a,
    ST_GeomFromText
      ('LINESTRING(-118.282340 34.018824,-118.289132 34.020923,-118.287198 34.023338,-118.282791 34.021858,-118.280270 34.022503)') 
    AS b)
  AS Foo)
```

When I run this query with ST_Overlaps then it gives me false while ST_Intersects give me true. But When I build KML file and visualize it in google earth then I see the two polygons overlapping also. Can some one tell me why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the Geometry to a polygon and not a line string.

Comment: Ya i too found the same thing...now its working:-SELECT ST_Overlaps(a,b) As a_overlap_b FROM (SELECT ST_MAKEPOLYGON(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(-118.291686 34.018886,-118.292677 34.022562,-118.291231 34.025650,-118.2906224 34.0244091,-118.286493 34.020362,-118.291686 34.018886)')) As a,ST_MAKEPOLYGON(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(-118.282340 34.018824,-118.289132 34.020923,-118.287198 34.023338,-118.282791 34.021858,-118.280270 34.022503,-118.282340 34.018824)')) As b)As Foo;